# How to read incoming stream from API in flutter using http package asynchronously?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, stream

I am working on a Flutter application that needs to receive data from an API as a stream and process each chunk of data as soon as it is received. My API sends data in chunks, and I want to read this data in my Flutter app and print the chunk values as they arrive.

I have tried using the `http` package for making the request, but I am not sure how to listen to the incoming stream and process the chunked data in real-time. Here's my current code:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void fetchData() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://my-api-server.com/stream');
  final client = http.Client();

  try {
    final request = http.Request('GET', url);
    final response = await client.send(request);

    // How to read and print the chunks from the response stream?
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
```

How can I modify this code to listen to the incoming stream, process each chunk as it is received, and print the chunk values in real-time? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `response.stream.listen(print)`

Comment: more on streams here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Answer (score 1):

To listen to an incoming stream and process each chunk of data as it is received in Flutter, you can utilize the http package's stream property. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

### Solution Code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void fetchData() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://my-api-server.com/stream');
  final client = http.Client();

  try {
    final request = http.Request('GET', url);
    final response = await client.send(request);

    // Read and print the chunks from the response stream
    await for (var chunk in response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
      // Process each chunk as it is received
      print(chunk);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
```

In this code, we use the stream property of the http.Response object and transform it using utf8.decoder to convert the incoming bytes into a readable string.

By using the await for loop, we can iterate over the chunks as they arrive in real-time. Each chunk will be processed and printed using print(chunk) in this example. You can replace the print(chunk) line with your desired logic for processing the data.

Remember to import the dart:convert package to access the utf8.decoder for decoding the incoming stream.

With these modifications, your Flutter app will be able to receive the data in chunks from the API and process them as they arrive.

Hope that helps, let me know your feedback, Thanks, Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you for posting. I have been working with a variation of this code, but the complete stream gets printed only once at the end.

When I test my endpoint using 'curl --no-buffer http://127.0.0.1:8000/', it works as expected, printing out each value as it is broadcast to the listener.

Comment: Oxd..Great , Thanks for your feedback..kindly upvote the answer if it helped solving an issue, so that others can also benefit. Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

fread fwrite you can treat files as big data, with pyton or visual basic or .net, you need to stablish a buffer